# How to get the UserId from AssignedTo in a workitem in VisualStudio Services

Tags: c#, tfs, userid, workitem

I'm getting a workitem in `VSS Services` using `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi`. I get correctly the workitem, but i want to get the userId or the class IdentityRef to retrieve it from `System.AssignedTo` property. But the value i'm getting from this field is the simple string of "*Name <Email>*". Is there a way to get it?

```
            WorkItem wit = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(Id).Result;
            return wit.Fields["System.AssignedTo"] // This is a string, not a User class or Identity class for retrieve the user Id;
```

EDIT: By browser i can view the UserId of the System.AssignedTo property. The problem is by using library

Comment: Are you able to get UserId from User Entitlements API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more as workaround because I did not find direct method to get user properties. You can use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi`:

1. With `TeamHttpClient.GetTeamsAsync`, you can get all teams in team project
2. `TeamHttpClient.GetTeamMembersWithExtendedPropertiesAsync` returns all team members with id, email etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a way to get UserId of the System.AssignedTo property directly. You could use the following API to get UserId after you getting UserEmail from System.AssignedTo property:

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1